# git cant resolve rebase conflicts as mergetool doesnt pop up

Tags: git, visual-studio, merge, git-merge, rebase

I am performing a rebase in my current branch 'MyUseCaseTest' with the master branch.

I get merge conflicts which I attempt to resove using my configured mergetool which is vsdiffmerge. Here is the .gitconfig file

```
[diff]
    tool = vsdiffmerge
[difftool]
      prompt = false
[difftool "vsdiffmerge"]
      cmd = '"%VSINSTALLDIR%Common7/IDE/vsdiffmerge.exe"' "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" //t
      keepbackup = false
      trustexitcode = true
[merge]
      tool = vsdiffmerge
[mergetool]
      prompt = false
[mergetool "vsdiffmerge"]
      cmd = '"%VSINSTALLDIR%Common7/IDE/vsdiffmerge.exe"' "$REMOTE" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$MERGED" //m
      keepbackup = false
      trustexitcode = true
```

Here are the commands I have tried to get vsdiffmerge tool to pop up,

```
git mergetool
git mergetool -t vsdiffmerge
```

but they dont and give this error instead

```
$ git mergetool -t vsdiffmerge
Merging:
src/OneDirection.cs
src/CustomBatch.cs

Normal merge conflict for 'src/OneDirection.cs':   
{local}: modified file   
{remote}: modified file 
/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib: line 136: fg: no job control 
merge of src/OneDirection.cs failed 
Continue merging other unresolved paths (y/n) ?
```

I click on yes and get the same error, but for the other file. I dont know what is wrong and how to fix it. The manuals don't explain this scenario. I couldn't find anything that explains what is going on or how to fix it.

Please help.

Comment: Keep in mind a rebase applies multiple commits sequentially so it's possible to see the same conflict, or the same file conflicted, repeatedly if each subsequent commit is producing/reproducing a conflict. If there's a manageable amount of commits you might be able to just merge your way through them. (This may not be your issue, but the situation I've described has happened to me.)

Comment: I think it could also be a problem with my mergetool, but I couldn't be sure. Is there a way to configure two different merge tools ?

Comment: Try using full path like `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/vsdiffmerge.exe"`. Full path worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue and orad's answer pointed me in the right direction - the path was the problem (I'm still not used to linux-style paths...) and what ended up working for me was this:

```
[diff]
    tool = vsdiffmerge
[difftool]
  prompt = false
[difftool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/vsdiffmerge.exe\" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" //t
    keepbackup = false
    trustexitcode = true
[merge]
    tool = vsdiffmerge
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
[mergetool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/vsdiffmerge.exe\" "$REMOTE" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$MERGED" //m
    keepbackup = false
    trustexitcode = true
```

Although it'd be really nice to be able to use %VSINSTALLDIR% to avoid the absolute file paths.  Thanks to [Mark Kadlec](http://mkadlec99.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/setting-up-correct-git-config.html) for showing the right syntax.

Answer (score -2):

Once you get conflict, you can simply open that file and search for HEAD to see the place of conflict and resolve it manually.